# Connecting 2 unconnected tables but are connected to the same table via many-to-many relations

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

I have the following setting in a django project

A model describing "Person", this model includes 2  many-to-many relation fields
a. The first unit field connects to a Unit model (m2m)
b. The second tool field connects to a Tools model (m2m)

Unit and Tools are not directly connected, but I want to list all the tools used in a given unit.

I'm not sure how this can be done, since the two tables are not connected?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit = models.ManyToManyField(Unit, blank=True)
    rtools = models.ManyToManyField(Rtool, blank=True)

class Tool(models.Model):
    tool_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tool_description = models.TextField( blank= True)

class Unit(models.Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

** --- I found a working solution in the views part

I decompose the search into 2 successive joints.

1. For a given unit, I first create a queryset of the persons member of that unit (that I called persons);
2. Then I can use that queryset to filter the tools used by these persons using the __in

This is working fine, but I am not sure, if this is the best way to do this?

```
def unit_detail(request, slug):
    unit = get_object_or_404(Unit, slug=slug)
    persons = Person.objects.filter(unit=unit) 
    tools = Rtool.objects.filter(
        person__in = researchers).distinct()

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it so Im not sure if this will work, also I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but you can try to do something like that:

views.py:

```
instance_unit = Unit.objects.get(id=<id of unit>)

units = Person.objects.filter(unit=instance_unit)
```

templates.py

```
    {% for tools in units %}

        {{ tools.rtools.tool_name }}

    {% endfor %}
```

As I said, haven't tested and Im not sure if thats the result that you want.

Comment: Thank you. I does not work, but it led me to the solution !  See the answer that I will post